# deploying go project to heroku error: cannot find package in any of

Tags: go, heroku

I've seen many people with similar problems posted on SO, but no solutions have worked for me so far. I'm trying to use govendor to deploy. My file setup:

```
vendor
  /github.com
    /gorilla
      /websockets
  vendor.json
Procfile (only text is "web: [my_app_name]")    
MyAppBinaryFile
```

This is my `vendor.json` file:

```
{
  "comment": "",
  "ignore": "test",
  "package": [],
  "heroku": {
    "install" : [ "./..." ],
    "goVersion": "go1.9"
  },
  "rootPath": "github.com/[my_acct]/hackernews"
}
```

This is my GOPATH: `GOPATH="/Users/[my_account_name]/go"`

This is my GOROOT: `GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.2/libexec"`

This is my error:

```
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Fetching jq... done
remote: -----> Checking vendor/vendor.json file.
remote:  !!
remote:  !!    Deprecated or unsupported version of go (go1.9.4)
remote:  !!    See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-support#go-versions for supported version information.
remote:  !!
remote: -----> Installing go1.9.4
remote: -----> Fetching go1.9.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz... done
remote: -----> Fetching govendor... done
remote: -----> Fetching any unsaved dependencies (govendor sync)
remote: -----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku ./...
remote: websockets/service.go:9:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/websocket" in any of:
remote:     /tmp/tmp.VCgbsN65Ud/.go/src/github.com/[my_app]/hackernews/vendor/github.com/gorilla/websocket (vendor tree)
remote:     /app/tmp/cache/go1.9.4/go/src/github.com/gorilla/websocket (from $GOROOT)
remote:     /tmp/tmp.VCgbsN65Ud/.go/src/github.com/gorilla/websocket (from $GOPATH)
```

I have my binary here, not in the `/bin` directory, although I've copied this file to the `/bin` directory as well with no luck.

I've followed the heroku tutorial, and can build/deploy their sample app (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go#deploy-the-app). I've tried changing to godep and even glide.

This issue (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/issues/136) looks very similar from the logs outputting the error, but I my /vendor file is checked in.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is that your full `vendor.json` file? It should contain an array of the app's dependencies as seen here: https://github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/blob/master/vendor/vendor.json To add the deps to vendor.json run `govendor add +external`

Comment: Also your file setup shows `.../gorilla/websockets` while the package's actual name is singular (no "s" at the end), not sure if this is just a typo in the question or if it reflects your actual file setup...

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks! The issue was I hadn't added the deps to my vendor.json! As a follow up to your other question: I made a typo when writing my file structure above, in reality the path was .../gorilla/websocket